# How to check if selected file aready existed in kendo upload?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I want to understand why we check index array values with -1 , I have a issue with kendo upload `onSelect` if fileName is already existed prevent user to load file and display `showErr`. it works when we work with one file but when we selecte multiples files and if one file is already loaded it should dispaly showErr but its not happening.

main.html

```
 <div class="row" >
                <div class="form-group col-md-12 fieldHeight" ng-hide="errorUpDoc" >
                    <label for="attachment" class="col-md-4" ng-show="!editDocMode">File name:</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6" ng-show="!editDocMode">
                         <input name="file"
                   type="file"
                   kendo-upload="fileAttachment"
                   k-upload="addMorePostParameters"
                   k-success="onSuccess"
                   k-error = "onError"
                   k-multiple="true"
                   ng-disabled="disableDocFields"
                   k-options="fileAttachmentOptions"
                   k-select="onSelect"
                   k-remove="onUploadRemove"
                   />
                   <p ng-show="showErr" class="text-danger">File name already exists</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

main.js

```
 $scope.onSelect = function (e) {
       // var fileNames = $.map(e.files, function(file) { return file.name; }).join(', ');
        var fileNames = assessmentData.map(function(assessment)
            { return assessment.fileName; });
           e.files.forEach(function (file) {
          if (fileNames.indexOf(file.name) !== -1 || selectedFile.indexOf(file.name) !== -1) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $timeout(function () {
              $scope.showErr= true;
              });
          }
          else {
              $timeout(function () {
                  $scope.showErr = false;
                  });
            }
          });
        for ( var i=0; i < e.files.length; i++){
            if(selectedFile.indexOf(e.files[i].name) === -1){
                selectedFile.push(e.files[i].name);
            }
        }
      };
```

Comment: `indexOf` return -1 if item is not found in the array.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Reading the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is always useful.

Comment: I dont understand down voting

Comment: The tooltip of the DV button says: "This question does not show any research effort", that explains a lot?

Comment: I tried to improved it

Comment: Looks like asking about `indexOf` has shadowed your main problem. The post is better now, but down voters rarely coming back and check if you've improved your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the element doesn't exist in the array, `indexOf` returns -1.

Answer (score 1):

An index of `-1` means that the value has no index in the array.